# How do I use the MIDIUtil library without raising an Import Error?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, midi

I have already got MIDIUtil to work in the past without an import error on my Mac. For some reason, it has now stopped working and throws an import error, no matter how I try to change the file directory or the name of the module in my code:

```
ImportError: No module named midiutil
```

I am just trying to run the 'example' file located in the package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from midiutil import MIDIFile

degrees  = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 72]  # MIDI note number
track    = 0
channel  = 0
time     = 0    # In beats
duration = 1    # In beats
tempo    = 60   # In BPM
volume   = 100  # 0-127, as per the MIDI standard

MyMIDI = MIDIFile(1)  # One track
MyMIDI.addTempo(track, time, tempo)

for i, pitch in enumerate(degrees):
    MyMIDI.addNote(track, channel, pitch, time + i, duration, volume)

with open("major-scale.mid", "wb") as output_file:
    MyMIDI.writeFile(output_file)
```

I have read some stack overflow posts on this subject, who recommend:

```
from midiutil.MidiFile import MIDIFile
```

and:

```
from midiutil.MidiFile3 import MIDIFile
```

I seem to have tried every option, but there is definitely something that I am missing!

I am a beginner at Python and coding in general so thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The package was installed successfully? Are you using the correct Python installation?

Comment: I would try re-installing the package.  https://pypi.org/project/MIDIUtil/

Comment: @AMC, yes, as far as I know. I have the most up-to-date version of pip and got this: `pip install MIDIutil
Requirement already satisfied: MIDIutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.2.1)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have reinstalled the newest version of the library, but no change.

Comment: @CallumMurray Is the script being executed using the same Python installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a `venv` created virtual enviroment, this can happen when your python version is upgraded (and the previous verion of python removed from the system).  When the python version is upgraded the virtualenv will still activate without an error but it doesn't actually work so if the script is depending on importing a module from the virtualenv, it won't find the module.

The solution is use the `--upgrade` flag to update the venv to use the current python version.  Example:`python -v venv <name-of-venv> --upgrade`.  After upgrading MIDIUtil and other modules in the venv should work correctly.